# Switch statement embedded in if-statement (java)

Tags: java

I have the following code that won't compile. Error message is that it's missing a return statement. Was wondering if someone could explain to me why that is, since I thought I covered all cases in the if-else block.

```
    public static boolean method1(String[] statement) {
        String[] array1 = new String[statement.length];

        if (array1.length == 2) {
            switch (array1[0]) {
                case "a":
                    return true;
                case "b":
                    return false;
            }
        } else return true;
    }
```

Also I know this code is useless, just showing it as an example.

Comment: Add a default case to the switch statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are missing is a `default` statement in your `switch` case

```
public static boolean method1(String[] statement) {
    String[] array1 = new String[statement.length];

    if (array1.length == 2) {
        switch (array1[0]) {
            case "a":
                return true;
            case "b":
                return false;
            default: 
                return true;
        }
    } else return true;
}
```

The `default` case will then handle the cases when the value of `array1[0]` is neither `a` nor `b`